# Cucumber-like table steps in rspec/minitest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, cucumber, minitest

I was wondering if there was anything out there to help me input tabular test vectors into my rspec and/or minitest tests? Like the tables you can have in Cucumber steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use Cucumber, I suppose people who read your code will be you or peer developers.

In this case you are free to use Array or Hash or `%w{}` tags to represent the "table" in cucumber, they are much cleaner than "table" in developers' eyes.

Comment: I was thinking that's probably what I'd have to do. Just thought I'd check with the community. My 2-dimensional test vectors would be a bit nicer to read in tabular form. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. The table is intuitive, but hash could be more concise using together with FactoryGirl.